# Pandorable way to reference a column of a filtered dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
>>>df
      Source              Log  Size
0        USB         file.txt   256
1  Bluetooth         song.wav    75
2        USB  spreadsheet.xls   129
```

I want to splice based on column `Source` and then select only column `Log`. The following code works but I don't think it's the pandorable way to write it because I've read that it's not proper to use back to back brackets `][`.

```
df[df['Source'] == 'USB']['Log']
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Probably, the most pandorable way is to use [.loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data) with boolean indexing.

You can use `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Source'] =="USB",'Log']
```

Output:

```
0           file.txt
2    spreadsheet.xls
Name: Log, dtype: object
```

## Or a more readable syntax using [.query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental).

You can use `query`:

```
df.query('Source == "USB"')['Log']
```

Output:

```
0           file.txt
2    spreadsheet.xls
Name: Log, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the `][` isn't really good style because it's a sign that you're not taking full advantage of multidimensional slicing that NumPy and Pandas provide. But in other cases it's perfectly fine (like in your case) because you do completly different (and incompatible) operations.

The `[df['Source'] == 'USB']` does a [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) and the `['Log']` makes a column lookup.

My opinion: No need to change anything here.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be

```
df.Log[df['Source'] == 'USB']
```

It will return

```
0           file.txt
2    spreadsheet.xls
```